# Blazor WebAssembly PWA - IFormFile FromForm is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, azure-cognitive-services, blazor-client-side

I have setup a  `Blazor WebAssembly ASP.Net Core hosted PWA` project and am using `Azure Cognitive Services` in it. Therefore I have in one of my client-views a form where the user can upload an image and this will be referred to Azure.

In the razor-view I have this:

```cs
@inject HttpClient client;
@inject IFileReaderService FileReader;
@inject NavigationManager navi;

<div class="text-center">
    <input class="btn btn-secondary " name="file" @ref="InpReference" type="file" id="file-selector" placeholder="Brows" accept="image/*" capture="camera" @onclick="InputFile">

    @if (_fileSelected != false)
    {
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" role="button" id="startbutton" @onclick="Upload" value="upload" />
    }
</div>

@code {
        private async Task Upload()
        {
            // content base structure
            MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
    
            
            foreach (/*IFileReference*/var fileReference in fileReferences)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("test1");
                // getting the file size
                IFileInfo fileinfo = await fileReference.ReadFileInfoAsync();
                Stream fileStream;
                var fileReferencesArray = fileReferences.ToArray();
                using (var fs = await fileReference.CreateMemoryStreamAsync((int)fileinfo.Size))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("test2");
                    fileStream=new MemoryStream(fs.ToArray());
                }
                Console.WriteLine("test4" + fileinfo.Size);
                StreamContent sc = new StreamContent(fileStream, (int)fileStream.Length);
                content.Add(sc, "file", fileinfo.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("test5");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("test6");
            var response = await client.PostJsonAsync<List<Prediction>>("api/Azure/Prediction", content);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Count + " : " + response.GetType().ToString());
            foreach (var prediction in  response)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prediction.Id + ":" + prediction.Name + "," + prediction.Probability.ToString());
            }
            navi.NavigateTo("detailView/");
    
    
        }
}
```

My WebApi Controller for the handling:

```cs
    ...
        [HttpPost]
        public List<Prediction> getPrediction([FromForm]IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file == null)
            {
                return new List<Prediction>();
            }
            List<Prediction> predicitions = azure_Client.GetPrediction(file.OpenReadStream());
            return predicitions;
        }
    ...
```

The problem is that the `[FromForm]IFormFile file` in the controller is always `null`. This is only null in the `PWA` project. I have set the same project up without `PWA` and it **works**, it is not `null` and it is getting the selected image from the view! What is the difference there and why isn't the `HttpClient` doing the same as in the `Blazor WebAssembly ASP.Net Core hosted`?

Comment: I want to say this has to do with JSInterop.  You would probably have to grab something like InputFile off nuget, since there wasn't a built in method other than http which has slight issues as you see from dealing with this.   https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorInputFile or go with something like syncfusion's control.  In addition the blog post by author of InputFile https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/13/blazor-inputfile/

Comment: Please refer to https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/13/blazor-inputfile/

Comment: @mvermef Thanks! I will look up onto that and will include that into  the project.

Comment: @JimXu Thanks too! I will take a look onto thatt and will include that into the project.

Comment: Unrelated, but may I suggest that you consider directly uploading into azure storage. There are a few JS libraries, like uppy, that will allow you to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my test, if you want to upload file in Blazor WebAssembly ASP.Net Core hosted PWA, please refer to the following steps

1. Client(I use the sdk `Tewr.Blazor.FileReader`)

   a. update `Program.cs`

   ```
   builder.Services.AddFileReaderService(options => {
             options.UseWasmSharedBuffer = true;
         });
         builder.Services.AddTransient(sp =>
             new HttpClient
             {
                 BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)
             });
   ```

   b. upload file razor-view

```
@using System.IO
@using Blazor.FileReader

@inject HttpClient client;
@inject IFileReaderService fileReader
<h1>File uplaod Blzaor WebAssembly!</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" name="image" @ref="inputReference" @onchange="async() =>await OpenFile()" />
            <ul>
                <li>File Name: @fileName</li>
                <li>Size: @size</li>
                <li>Type: @type</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-success" @onclick="async() =>await UploadFile()"> Upload File</button>
        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
        {
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                File has been uplaoded
            </div>

        }
    </div>   
</div>


@code{
    ElementReference inputReference;
    string message = string.Empty;
    string fileName = string.Empty;
    string type = string.Empty;
    string size = string.Empty;
    Stream fileStream=null;

    async Task UploadFile()
    {
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
        var sc = new StreamContent(fileStream, (int)fileStream.Length);
        content.Add(sc, "image", fileName);


        var response = await client.PostAsync("/upload", content);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            message = "OK";
        }

    }

    async Task OpenFile()
    {
        var file = (await fileReader.CreateReference(inputReference).EnumerateFilesAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

        if (file == null) {
            return;
        }

        var fileInfo=await file.ReadFileInfoAsync();
        fileName = fileInfo.Name;
        type = fileInfo.Type;
        size = $"{fileInfo.Size} Bytes";

        using (var ms = await file.CreateMemoryStreamAsync((int)fileInfo.Size)) {
            fileStream = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }



}
```

2. Server

API COntroller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm(Name ="image")]IFormFile file) {

            if (file == null || file.Length == 0) {
                return BadRequest("do not receive file");
            }

            var fileName = file.FileName;
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            var newFileName = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}{extension}";
            var filePath = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "Images", newFileName);
            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "Images"))) {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "Images"));
            
            }
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
            
            return Ok(filePath);
        
        }
```

3. Result

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My solution is not far away from this solution but I will take some changes from yours to mine. One question, where does the `builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAdress` come from? By default it is not working for me. It is telling me that `WebAssemblyHostBuilder` does not contain `HostEnvironment` in the client `Program.cs`.

Comment: @brstkr I use .net core 3.1 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Templates 3.2.0 to create project. Then `WebAssemblyHostBuilder`  contains `HostEnvironment` :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.hosting.webassemblyhostbuilder?view=aspnetcore-3.1.

Comment: @brstkr Besides, if you cannot run the code `BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)`, it also has no problem. It just set the project address(like https://localhost:4436) as the `HttpClient` base address.

Comment: Ok thanks. Well I tried the code like here and set a breakpoint at the controller, to check the `[FromForm(Name=“Image”)IFormFile file]` And it is still `null`. Is this again specific with my WebAssembly Template version?

Comment: I am also using .Net Core 3.1 and in the project the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server` is also `3.2.0-preview3.20168.3` but it is still not working. I think the problem is at the `HttpClient` because of no `IFormFile file` was given to the Server-side API-Controller.

Comment: Ok I have found it out. It has to be version specific. Just created after updating the packages and templates antoher new WebAssembly ASP.Net Core hosted PWA application and tried it with the same code and it worked.